# Panel from nested dictionary with different value lengths

Tags: python, pandas

I have a nested dictionary, where the first level is individuals' names, and in the second level I have characteristics.
This is what a generic entry looks like:

```
    dems = {'Surname, Name': {'Birth Date': ['March 26, 1938'],
      'Fav color': ['Yellow'],
      'Fav team': ['Lazio'],
      'Fav party': ['FI, 1994-2010', 'PCI, 1986-1987']}}
```

I.e., I have a bunch of keys in the nested dictionary, of which the 'Fav party' one may have multiple values, while all the others have only one value.
I would like to convert this into a panel dataset using Pandas, but when I do this:

```
    pd.Panel.from_dict(dems)
```

I get

```
    ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

Is there a way to tell Python to replicate all the invariant values as many times as is the length of the longest among them?

EDIT:
Following EdChum's comment:

```
my_df=pd.Panel.from_dict(dems, orient='minor')


In [230]: my_df.major_xs(my_df.major_axis[0])
Out[232]: 
                    Birth Date      Fav color   Fav team    Fav party
Surname, Name       March 26, 1938  Yellow      Lazio       FI, 1994-2010


In [230]: my_df.major_xs(my_df.major_axis[1])
Out[231]: 
                    Birth Date      Fav color   Fav team    Fav party
Surname, Name       NaN             NaN         NaN         PCI, 1986-1987
```

And this is what I would like to get

```
In [230]: my_df.major_xs(my_df.major_axis[0])
Out[232]: 
                    Birth Date      Fav color   Fav team    Fav party
Surname, Name       March 26, 1938  Yellow      Lazio       FI, 1994-2010


In [230]: my_df.major_xs(my_df.major_axis[1])
Out[231]: 
                    Birth Date      Fav color   Fav team    Fav party
Surname, Name       March 26, 1938  Yellow      Lazio       PCI, 1986-1987
```

Comment: Sorry are you asking for `pd.panel.from_dict(dems, orient='minor')`?

Comment: Thank you. That's in the direction of what I was looking for, but I would like to get all the invariant characteristics on each line, whereas this way I only get them in the first line. Should I edit the question to add an example?

Comment: Please post more info and desired output